# CSS animation Not Working in Firefox?

Tags: css

Hello Friends This is my css code.

```
.create_animation{
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
    background-image: url("animation/background.jpg"),url("animation/background.jpg");
    background-size: 100px 100px,100% 100%;
    background-repeat: no-repeat,repeat;
    animation: myfirst 5s 2s forwards;
    -moz-animation: myfirst 5s 2s forwards;
    -webkit-animation: myfirst 5s 2s forwards;
    -webkit-animation-delay: 4s;
    -moz-animation-delay: 4s;
}


@-moz-keyframes myfirst
{
0%   { -moz-opacity: 0.8; -moz-background-size: 100px 100px,100% 100%;}
25%  { -moz-background: url("animation/vahan1.png"), url("animation/background_girl.jpg"); -moz-background-position: 20px 90px, 0px 0px; -moz-background-repeat: no-repeat,no-repeat; -moz-background-size:  100px 100px,100% 100%;}
50%  { -moz-background: url("animation/vahan1.png"), url("animation/background_girl.jpg"); -moz-background-position: 40px 90px, 0px 0px; -moz-background-repeat: no-repeat,no-repeat; -moz-background-size:  100px 100px,100% 100%;}
100% { -moz-background: url("animation/vahan1.png"), url("animation/background_girl.jpg"); -moz-background-position: 60px 90px, 0px 0px; -moz-background-repeat: no-repeat,no-repeat; -moz-background-size:  100px 100px,100% 100%;}
}
```

This code is not working on firefox this working only chrome.

Comment: You don't need to add `-moz` before everything. `background`, `background-size` and `background-repeat`.

Comment: i try but not working after i add -moz- before every thing.

Comment: Get rid of every `-moz` within the `myfirst` keyframe (but keeping in `-moz-keyframes`).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`background-image` is non-animatable in Firefox. Check the spec [HERE](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-image)

Comment: please check this url is working on firefox. http://www.w3schools.com/css/tryit.asp?filename=trycss3_animation1

Comment: @renishkhunt that example is animating `background-color` not `background-image`

Answer (score 1):

Get rid of every `-moz` within the `myfirst` keyframe (but keeping in `-moz-keyframes`).

Eg:

```
@-moz-keyframes myfirst
{
  0%   { opacity: 0.8; background-size: 100px 100px,100% 100%;}
  25%  { background: url("animation/vahan1.png"), url("animation/background_girl.jpg"); background-position: 20px 90px, 0px 0px; background-repeat: no-repeat,no-repeat; background-size:  100px 100px,100% 100%;}
  50%  { background: url("animation/vahan1.png"), url("animation/background_girl.jpg"); background-position: 40px 90px, 0px 0px; background-repeat: no-repeat,no-repeat; background-size:  100px 100px,100% 100%;}
  100% { background: url("animation/vahan1.png"), url("animation/background_girl.jpg"); background-position: 60px 90px, 0px 0px; background-repeat: no-repeat,no-repeat; background-size:  100px 100px,100% 100%;}
}
```

However, `background-image` is not animatable in Firefox as of yet.